# Listen for View (List Header) onTouch event and disable scroll on ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm basically trying to disable scroll on the list view when the user touches the List Header and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is performed.

*If you are wondering on why this crazy implementation?* - I'm basically building a custom seekbar on my listView Header which works on `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and since the view is a header of list view it should not scroll until user takes off touch from this custom header view.

**So my question/problem is.**

For now i have 2 java classes. Activity (which has this list view) and the custom Header (which is a `View` implementing `OnTouchListener`).

1. **How do I pass value when my header view is touched to this list view (activity) to disable scrolling?**
2. **It seems that list view scroll can be disabled by overriding `dispatchTouchEvent` as said [here](http://blog.siegerstein.com/archives/206). Since mine is not a custom listView is it possible to disable in activity class itself?**

Sorry i'm just learning, so please dont mind my newbiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have gone little quiet far on the question I asked, So I'm answering the first half of my question.

**How do I pass value when my header view is touched to this list view (activity) to disable scrolling?**

I got my solution in creating an `interface`. So I created a `public static interface` which has a `public void headerTouched(Boolean touchEvent);` method. My class which has the code for the `listView` is the `implementer` so it automatically overrides this method from the interface class. I this class I create a private variable (in my case: `boolean`) which listens for the boolean value returned from the driver class. My driver class is the HeaderView which has this interface object and through it I set the value. To help newbies on interface, I have posted my code below.

**Interface Class**

```
public static interface HeaderTouchListener{
    public void headerTouched(Boolean touchEvent);
}
```

**Implementer Class**

```
private boolean headerTouched = false;
public void headerTouched(Boolean touchEvent) {
    headerTouched = touchEvent;
}
```

**Driver Class**

```
HeaderTouchListener touchListner = new ImplementerClassName();
touchListner.headerTouched(true);
```

I'm still having trouble figuring out how to disable scroll on my list view. More information on it, please follow this question [Set dispatchTouchEvent for List View without creating custom List View class. (for disabling scroll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401164/set-dispatchtouchevent-for-list-view-without-creating-custom-list-view-class-f)