# Set dispatchTouchEvent for List View without creating custom List View class. (for disabling scroll)

Tags: android, list, listview, android-layout, android-listview

I'm basically trying to disable the scroll on List View. Which can be done by

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
       if(ev.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
       }

       super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
       return true;
    }
```

**But I do not want to create a custom List View (widget) class for this.**

Is there any way I could do it like `myListView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)`???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Well it seems there is no way to achieve this without extending to a custom list view class. So accepting this answer.